# Vue ChildComponent (GrandchildComponent) should update a list of the ParentComponent

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, pinia

I have a `DocumentView.vue` component. This component has a `DocumentListingView.Vue` component. The `DocumentListingView.vue` has a `DocumentItem.vue` componente. In the `DocumentItem.vue` componente the respective document can be deleted (by api call). After deletion I want the `DocumentListingView.vue` to be updated. That means that the child has to tell the parent, please update your `DocumentListingView` by firing a new api call. I know that with $emit and pinia store you can implement the child - parent communication. But I just don't know how it should look architecturally.

**Problem:** I am trying to implement it with pinia. Unfortunately I don't know the last step, how to update the data in the listing.

**Question:** What is the theoretical concept? The child element should update the list of the ParentView?

Below you can see the files I use for this. They are reduced to the essential: `DocumentView.vue` (Parent), `DocumentListingView.vue` (child), `DocumentItem.vue` (Grandchild), `apiData.js` (pinia).

#### DocumentView.vue

```js
<script setup>
  import { ref, computed as compi, onMounted } from 'vue'
  import DocumentListing from './document/DocumentListingView.vue'
  import { useApiDataStore } from '@/stores/apiData';
  
  let list = {};
  const apiData = useApiDataStore(); // init stores for api call
  
  async function getDocumentList() {  
    await apiData.refreshDocumentList();
    list = await apiData.listData;
  }    
  
  getDocumentList();
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <DocumentListing :documents="list"/>    
  </div>
</template>
```

#### DocumentListingView.vue

```js
<template>
    <h2>Documents</h2>
    <div class="documentListing">        
        <div v-for="item in documents">
            <DocumentItem :data="item"></DocumentItem>        
        </div>        
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
  import DocumentItem from '../../components/DocumentItem.vue'

  defineProps({
    documents: Object,
  })

</script>
```

#### DocumentItem.vue

```js
<script setup>
    import { useApiDataStore } from '@/stores/apiData';

    defineProps({
        data: Object,
    });
    
    const apiData = useApiDataStore();
    const removeDocument = async (document) => {
      // api call to remove document
      apiData.refreshDocumentList();
    }
    
</script>

<template>
  <div>
  <button @click="removeDocument(data)">Delete Doument></button>
  </div>
</template>
```

#### apiData.js

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useApiDataStore = defineStore('apiData', {
    id: 'apiData',
    state: () => ({
        listData: {}
    }),
    actions: {
        async refreshDocumentList() {
            const endpoint = "http://localhost:8888/api.php?list";
            const response = await fetch(endpoint);
            const json = await response.json();          
            this.listData = json;
        }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this, when you will use in you DocumentView.vue the state property `apiData.listData` instead of local list property. I commented the changes.

```js
<script setup>
  import { ref, computed as compi, onMounted } from 'vue'
  import DocumentListing from './document/DocumentListingView.vue'
  import { useApiDataStore } from '@/stores/apiData';
  
  // let list = {}; //remove this line
  const apiData = useApiDataStore(); // init stores for api call
  
  async function getDocumentList() {  
    await apiData.refreshDocumentList();
    // list = await apiData.listData; // remove this line
  }    
  
  getDocumentList();
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <DocumentListing :documents="apiData.listData"/>  <!--   replace list with  apiData.listData -->
  </div>
</template>
```